# REGEX in Winautomation

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse text the following email body text in Winautomation using this regex, `((^RITM).\s*).*`

The email content is:

> SCREQ0132501/RITM0200123/RITM0200125/RITM0200126/RITM0200127/RITM0200122/RITM0200124
>
> RITM0200123 : Microsoft Lync 2013 Account Creation (New Starter Pack)
>   RITM0200125 : Network Account Creation (New Starter Pack) RITM0200126
>   : Email Account Creation (New Starter Pack) RITM0200127 : Laptop over
>   the shoulder style carry case (New Starter Pack) RITM0200122 :
>   Standard laptop with docking station, keyboard and mouse (New Starter
>   Pack) RITM0200124 : File Folder and Group Access (New Starter Pack)
>
> ---
>
> REQUEST DETAILS

But it does not return any `RITM`. Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please specify exactly, what you want the output to be.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the output that I want are the text after SCREQ0132501/RITM0200123/RITM0200125/RITM0200126/RITM0200127/RITM0200122/RITM0200124 and before REQUEST DETAILS

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex is wrong: '`^`' Means 'start of string' - there's no `RITM` at start of string.
 '`\s`' will search for white `Space` after `RITM`, there's no White Space after `RITM`.

Try this instead:

```
RITM\d*
```

It will search for `RITM` anywhere, followed by zero or more `numbers`.

**Edit** according to comment:
Try this one:

```
RITM\d+ :.+
```

It should return the text, you want.

**Edit2**:

If you want a match for each RITM, separated, then you can use this:

```
RITM\d+ :(?:.(?!RITM))*
```

It returns a `Match` for each `RITM`.

Comment: Minor nitpick `RITM.\s` looks for RITM followed by a single character which isn't newline followed by whitespace.